Get return from a ZPL command
I'm sending some labels for printing via ZPL commands.
from zebra import Zebra
Zebra("S4M").output("""^XA~FDHello World^XZ""")  # print label

I checked in the zebra documentation that the ~HS command returns some status information, and this actually happens:

I would like to know if it is possible to obtain this response using a PYTHON script. I verified that the win32api/win32print library and Zebra are not able to do this.
I tried to get the status through zpl commands by python.

How is the printer connected?

It is connected via USB
